# How do I fix this issue with my navigation bar for Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation

Right, so I am creating a theme for Wordpress and never quite grasped the entire way CSS drop down menus work. I understand them enough for some parts, but I cannot make them properly without having some wierd workaround margins and stuff.

I am currently trying to fix the one hosted on my website: yenrac.net/theme

My CSS: http://pastebin.com/3sVLGLR8

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing some ul:hover and li:active properties, but my recomendation is that you use a CSS Framework like Bootstap or ZURB Foundation even if you don't want to use CSS pre processors this frameworks allow you to focus on  HTML layout building rather than CSS coding since they include lot of components ready to use including responsive menus.